# Taking an option from a dropdown menu and placing it into a specific spot an array

Tags: swift, xcode11

I'm creating an app in Xcode 11 and on one of the views, there is a series of several dropdown menus. Each dropdown menu has four different options for the user to choose from. When the user selects an option, that option is placed into a variable and then the option is placed into a specific spot in an array. However, for some reason, the selected option doesn't get loaded into the array unless I select it twice in a row. So basically, I have to click on the dropdown menu twice to get the option to be added to the array. The way I have the dropdown menus programmed is that each menu is actually a UIButton that expand when clicked on. I use the same code for each dropdown menu, so I distinguish which menu has been selected by taking a single variable (selectedButton) and assigning it to each button when that button is pressed.

I've done some testing, and it seems like my if-else statements are all logically sound, so I don't know why it doesn't work the first time? I'm not getting any errors or anything when I run the code. I'm a beginner in programming in both Xcode and swift, that's why it is comprised of mostly if-else statements.

Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var RCT1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var RCT2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var RCT3: UIButton!

var selectedButton = UIButton()
var dataSource = [String]()
var selectedAnswerArray : [String] = ["", "", ""]
var selectedAnswer : String = "blank"

@IBAction func RCT1Select(_ sender: Any) {
        dataSource = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
        selectedButton = RCT1
        if selectedButton == RCT1 && selectedAnswer == "test1"{
            selectedAnswerArray[0] = "test1"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT1 && selectedAnswer == "test2"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[0] = "test2"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT1 && selectedAnswer == "test3"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[0] = "test3"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT1 && selectedAnswer == "test4"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[0] = "test4"
        }
        else{
        }
        addTransparentView(frames: RCT1.frame)
    }

    @IBAction func RCT2Select(_ sender: Any) {
        selectedButton = RCT2
        dataSource = ["test5", "test6", "test7", "test8"]
        if selectedButton == RCT2 && selectedAnswer == "test5"{
            selectedAnswerArray[1] = "test5"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT2 && selectedAnswer == "test6"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[1] = "test6"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT2 && selectedAnswer == "test7"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[1] = "test7"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT2 && selectedAnswer == "test8"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[1] = "test8"
        }
        else{
        }
        addTransparentView(frames: RCT2.frame)
    }

    @IBAction func RCT3Select(_ sender: Any) {
        dataSource = ["test9", "test10", "test11", "test12"]
        selectedButton = RCT3
        if selectedButton == RCT3 && selectedAnswer == "test9"{
            selectedAnswerArray[2] = "test9"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT3 && selectedAnswer == "test10"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[2] = "test10"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT3 && selectedAnswer == "test11"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[2] = "test11"
        }
        else if selectedButton == RCT3 && selectedAnswer == "test12"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[2] = "test12"
        }
        else{
        }
        addTransparentView(frames: RCT3.frame)
    }

extension GamePage: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedButton.setTitle(dataSource[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        selectedAnswer = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        removeTransparentView()
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me figure out why it is not working or could point me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like your buttons need the variable selectedAnwer, but this one is only set after the tablecell was selected. So the button is probably truggered first but selected Answer is still "blank", then the tableview cell is selected and sets your variable. So only when you hit it a second time, the needed variable is set. It looks like you don't need buttons, since the interaction is already handled by the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am understanding exactly what you mean, but I will try my best. So it seems that in each method where a button gets clicked, the `selectedAnswer` variable is always blank, which prevents you from adjusting your `selectedAnswerArray`. I would also like to make some suggestions to your code so that it is a little bit cleaner without getting too complicated.

First, you make want to get rid of the boolean statement `selectedButton == RCT1` that you have for each if statement since you are setting the variable to be equal to RCT1 right before the if statements. Therefore, that statement is always going to be true.

Second, if there is no other code that under the last else statement, you can get rid of that. It is preferable to only include a final else statement when there is a piece of code that you want to be executed should all other if/else if statements are false.

Finally, to answer your question, you should assign a value to the variable `selectedAnswer` if you want to add a value to the `selectedAnswerArray` array. Based on your current code, none of the if statements will execute except for the last else statement (which doesn't have any code under that) because `selectedAnswer` is always blank. Therefore, you may want to assign a value such as "test1" or something so that one of the if statements will execute.

To give you a more cleaner version of your code, here is what I suggested.

```
@IBAction func RCT1Select(_ sender: Any) {
        dataSource = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
        selectedButton = RCT1
        //change the value of selectedAnswer so that one of the if statements will execute
        //I got rid of selectedButton == RCT1 since that will always return true
        if selectedAnswer == "test1"{
            selectedAnswerArray[0] = "test1"
        }
        else if selectedAnswer == "test2"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[0] = "test2"
        }
        else if selectedAnswer == "test3"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[0] = "test3"
        }
        else if selectedAnswer == "test4"
        {
            selectedAnswerArray[0] = "test4"
        }
        //Don't need a final else statement if nothing is going to run under that  
        addTransparentView(frames: RCT1.frame)
}
```

Obviously this code can be a lot cleaner, but since you are a beginner, I hope that you would at least understand some of the suggestions that I made. Based on your experience, I recommend watching this podcast that teaches Swift in the link below

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/developing-ios-11-apps-with-swift/id1315130780

If you watch the first episode, the professor will address a lot of the common mistakes that beginners tend to make in more details so that you can understand.

Good luck and hopefully I fixed your problem